# Postfix Domain Whitelisting in Combination with Sender Authentication

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I'd like to whitelist several domains in my Postfix configuration in such a way that all e-mails from those domains are accepted as long as they're properly authenticated using SPF and/or DKIM, should it be used by that domain. This means that e-mails coming from those domains should *not* be subjected to the usual DNSBL and Greylisting process, only to a SPF and DKIM verification.

Right now I have managed to save e-mails coming from those domains from the Greylisting milter by configuring a `sender_access` file and using the `postmap` utility to convert it to a suitable hash-database.

**main.cf**:

```
...
parent_domain_matches_subdomains = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks
  permit_sasl_authenticated
  reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
  reject_unauth_destination
  check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
  check_policy_service unix:private/tumgreyspf
...
```

**sender_access**:

```
domain1.com OK
domain2.net OK
```

I've found out about [postscreen](http://www.postfix.org/postscreen.8.html) and also found a [neat little example](http://rob0.nodns4.us/postscreen.html), but it appears like that is a DNSBL-only measure and is only slightly helpful in my case.

Comment: How about the other domains outside them? Should they checked for DNSBL, GreyList, SPF, and DKIM?

Comment: Well, yes, all other domains are supposed to be checked using all methods available, which are DNSBL, Greylisting, SPF and DKIM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever your restriction can't be applied globally to all cases, you can use [Postfix restriction classes](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html). The idea is excluding some domains to separate restrictions.

I reorder your current configuration on following principles "lightweight checks should executed before heavy ones". So, I suggest the configuration became

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks
  permit_sasl_authenticated
  reject_unauth_destination
  check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
  reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org    
  check_policy_service unix:private/tumgreyspf
```

Now, **postfix restriction classes** should be applied via this line `check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access`. Before that define the **smtpd_restriction_classes** parameter in `main.cf`.

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = whitelistdomain
whitelistdomain = 
  check_policy_service unix:private/tumgreyspf
```

Therefore the content of `/etc/postfix/sender_access` became

```
example.com  whitelistdomain
example.org  whitelistdomain
```

The logic is, postfix will apply default restrictions (**permit_mynetwork, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination**) to all domain. Then because example.com and example.org in *whitelistdomain class*, postfix only performs **check_policy_service unix:private/tumgreyspf**. Other domains should passed default restrictions.

---

Now, the problem is how configure `tumgreyspf` to exclude those domains from greylisting.

Based on [this page](http://bogdan.org.ua/2013/08/07/debian-how-to-whitelist-ip-address-in-tumgrey-spf.html), here the step to exclude **greylisting**. Note this path is applied to Debian. Other system may have different path.

First, create a folder for every domain

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/tumgreyspf/config/envelope_sender/example.com/
mkdir -p /var/lib/tumgreyspf/config/envelope_sender/example.org/
```

Create file configuration in `/etc/tumgreyspf/disablegreylist.conf`

```
SPFSEEDONLY = 0
GREYLISTTIME = 600
CHECKERS = spf
OTHERCONFIGS =
```

Now, symlink it into each of the domain directory

```
ln -s /etc/tumgreyspf/disablegreylist.conf /var/lib/tumgreyspf/config/envelope_sender/example.org/__default__
ln -s /etc/tumgreyspf/disablegreylist.conf  /var/lib/tumgreyspf/config/envelope_sender/example.com/__default__
```

More info, [github page of tumgreyspf](https://github.com/linsomniac/tumgreyspf)

Answer (score 3):

Just sort your `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` accordingly. This list is processed from front to back. Some filters can return a reject or nothing (blacklists, spf; either it's a malicious sender or we don't know) or a permit (SASL, Networks, if they don't match, continue)

In your case it would be:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks
  permit_sasl_authenticated
  check_policy_service unix:private/tumgreyspf
  check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
  reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
  reject_unauth_destination
```

Local and authenicated senders are always allowed. For all others we check our `sender_access` file. If there's no match continue with blacklists, SPF and Greylisting.

Comment: Thank you. I've already tried this, but unfortunately it skips the SPF verification which is done using `tumgreyspf`.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to put SPF in front =). I fixed it in the answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I guess it's a matter of configuring `tumgreyspf` to omit the whitelisted domains from the greylisting process but subjecting them to the SPF verification now.